# Using .on('scroll') and .each() function Run Once per each

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, each

My title might have been a little confusing but what I'm trying to do is use a scroll function which determines when an element enters the viewport and the run an each function each time the specified element enters. But I only want the function to run once.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
      $('.counter').each(function(index, value) {
           triggerpoint = $(window).height() * .8 + $(window).scrollTop();
           counterElement = $(this).offset().top;
           if(counterElement < triggerpoint) {
                $(this).countTo();
           }
      });
});
```

The problem is that every time I scroll it runs the `.countTo()` function on the `.counter` element again and again.
I only want the `.countTo()` function to run once for each `.counter` element.

Any help or ideas?

Comment: where is countTo function

Comment: share your html code please

Comment: I think u need to calc triggerpoint out of for loop.  but its just a wild guess u need to provide more js and html.

Answer (score 3):

So I ended up finding a solution to this problem.
I just added a class "element-visible" once the function ran once.
Then I added a simple if .hasClass statement at the beginning to determine if the element had already run through the function.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
$('.counter').each(function(index, value) {
if ( $(this).hasClass( "element-visible" ) ) {
  // do nothing
  }
   else {
  triggerpoint = $(window).height() * .8 + $(window).scrollTop(); // Call point in Viewport: viewport height * decimal(%) + pixels to top of window

  counterElement = $(this).offset().top;
  if  (counterElement < triggerpoint) {
    $(this).addClass("element-visible");
    $(this).countTo();  
    }
    }
    });
});
});
```